# HTML Color Bar how to?

Tags: html, css, colors

I have no idea how to go about this. I have tried to use an image, but can never get it to look right, but if I do it doesn't work well with other devices.

[Here's what I'm trying to model after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJn7o.png)

thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please post some code showing what you've tried so far

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just try to create a div with a height of 2px, with a linear-gradient background

```
<div class="br"></div>

.br {
    height: 2px;
    background: linear-gradient(YOUR COLORS HERE);
}
```

To create a radiant easily go to https://cssgradient.io/